# Stripe integration with flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe to flutter. I need to integrate in a way how Lyft/Uber does it. If a ride has been called then the payment is auto processed. I tried using stripe docs but it was no help. If someone can help me or guide me through would be wonderful, it is a project that I need it for.

Reguqiremnt:

payment sheet in the payment tab to add or select new card.
Automatically charge credit card upon agreeing to hail a ride.

Thanks.

Comment: Stripe has [a guide for setting up future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) but it doesn't cover Flutter.

Comment: Use this package `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe`. And if using Firebase, setup the `https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments` to connect with your Stripe account.